# Equation of Trajectory of a dog chasing a cat

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors, calculus

> A cat moves along the x-axis with a uniform velocity u. A dog moves with a uniform speed $v$ such that at every moment it is aimed towards the cat. Initially, at $t = 0$, the dog is perpendicular to the cat at a distance $l$ away from it. Find the equation of the trajectory of the dog.

**My Approach:**

(I used a hand-drawn diagram because I can't draw digitally)

[image]

Suppose the dog has a velocity $v$ at a given instant (say at time $t$). Now, its velocity vector shifts as shown in the figure after a time $dt$ when the cat travels a distance $u$  $dt$.
Now, clearly these shown triangles are similar.
Thus, we get
$$\frac{v \space sin \theta}{y} = \frac{v \space  d\theta}{u \space dt}$$
$$\implies dt = \frac{y \space  d\theta}{u \space sin \theta}$$
Now, we know,
$$dy = v \space sin \theta \space dt$$
$$\implies dy = v \space sin \theta \space \frac{y \space  d\theta}{u \space sin \theta}$$
$$\implies \frac{dy}{y} =   \frac{v \space  d\theta}{u }$$
$$\implies \int_{l}^{y} \frac{dy}{y} =   \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\theta}  \frac{v \space  d\theta}{u }$$
$$\implies ln( \frac{y}{l}) =   \frac{v \space  (\theta - \frac{\pi}{2} )}{u }$$
$$\therefore y =   l\space e^{\frac{v \space  (\theta - \frac{\pi}{2})}{u }}$$
Now, I tried using the fact that $\frac{dy}{dx} = tan \theta$ but the expression I obtained for $x$ in terms of $\theta$ was not something I could integrate. Please suggest how to compute for $x$ and if this flow of logic is correct.

Comment: $\tan \left( \theta \right) =v~$?  and $~ \dfrac{dx}{d\theta }=\dfrac{1}{v}\,\dfrac{dy}{d\theta }$

Comment: How is $\tan \theta = v$?